# Visualising a regression tree

Tags: regression, data-visualization, cart

I have a problem understanding how to draw a recursive representation of the regression tree corresponding to the greedy recursive partitioning procedure
with respect to square error.

For example, given the following data set
$${((1, 1),9), ((1,2), -4), ((1,3),2), ((2,2),4), ((2,3), 2)} $$ 
how would one approach drawing the regression tree and its binary representation?

Would the following representations be correct where the number in each leaf is the mean of the response for the observations that fall there.

[image]

Comment: The first split in the diagram at the left, t1, at "x2 <2" is on the wrong axis, given the figure on the right.  It should be "x1".  The second split, t2, is also on the incorrect axis.  The "t2" split breaks the x2 axis.   The "t" values are thresholds, where splits occur.  The mean tends to happen interior to the region.